# How do I combine multiple dummy variables into one variable in SPSS?

Tags: variable-assignment, spss

I have multiple dummy variables and I want to combine them into one variable. For ex. if variable A=1, then it is category 1, if variable B=1, then it is category 2, if variable C=1 it is category 3 etc. How do I do this on SPSS?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ways to do it, both assuming there are never cases where more then one of the variables A/B/C withe value 1:

The standard way, using a loop:

```
do repeat vr=A B C/vl=1 2 3.
   if vr=1 category=vl.
end repeat.
```

If the variables used here are consecutive in the file you can write the first line this way:

```
do repeat vr=A to G/vl=1 to 7.
```

And this is a different approach to the problem:

```
compute category=sum(1*A, 2*B, 3*C).
```